# Efeito scroll com opacity funciona mas com transfform não

Tags: javascript, css, transform

Boa noite, tenho este código que funciona uma parte e a outra não.

```
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
/* funciona */
    var max_opacity_arrow = 0.3;
    var min_opacity_arrow = 0.1;
    var opacity_arrow = max_opacity_arrow * (1 - $(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height());
    if (opacity_arrow > min_opacity_arrow) {
        opacity_arrow = opacity_arrow;
    } else {
        opacity_arrow = min_opacity_arrow; }
    $('div.home.show div.bottom.arrow').css('opacity', opacity_arrow);

/* não funciona */
    var max_pespective_rotatex = 0;
    var min_pespective_rotatex = 90;
    var rotateX = max_pespective_rotatex * (1 - $(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height());
    if (rotateX > min_pespective_rotatex) {
        rotateX = rotateX;
    } else {
        rotateX = min_pespective_rotatex; }
    $('div.primeirapagina div.mainpespective').css('transform', rotateX + 'deg'); });
```

A parte de baixo em questão é uma cópia da de cima, mas apenas quando utilizo o TRANSFORM que não funciona, se eu mudar ali no final .css('transform' o transform para qualquer outra coisa, ele funciona mas se devolvo o transform, não funciona, o que quero é que assim como quando rolo a página o arrow vai sumindo, quero que uma div vá girando até ficar de frente ou 0 como eu poderia fazer isso de outra maneira que funcione? grato desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinha dois problemas no seu código. Um era que você tava passando `transform: 90deg` ao invés de `transform: rotate(90deg)`. O outro é que a função que calcula o `rotateX` tava sempre dando o mesmo valor então ele não rodava. Esse eu não corrigi completamente, só inverti o sinal do if e adicionei um multiplicador pros valores saírem diferentes e caixinha rodar no exemplo.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
/* funciona */
    var max_opacity_arrow = 0.3;
    var min_opacity_arrow = 0.1;
    var opacity_arrow = max_opacity_arrow * (1 - $(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height());
    if (opacity_arrow > min_opacity_arrow) {
        opacity_arrow = opacity_arrow;
    } else {
        opacity_arrow = min_opacity_arrow; }
    $('div.home.show div.bottom.arrow').css('opacity', opacity_arrow);

/* não funciona */
    var max_pespective_rotatex = 1;
    var min_pespective_rotatex = 9;
    var rotateX = max_pespective_rotatex * (1 - $(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height());
    if (rotateX < min_pespective_rotatex) {
        rotateX = rotateX;
    } else {
        rotateX = min_pespective_rotatex; }
    
    $('div.primeirapagina div.mainpespective').css('transform', 'rotate('+rotateX*100+'deg)');
  });
```

```css
body {
    height: 5000px;
}
.bottom {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

.mainpespective {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home show">
  <div class="bottom arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="primeirapagina">
  <div class="mainpespective"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: funciona, realmente um erro de percepção, não reparei que faltava o totatex(), grato, mas ai você meu deu a luz para mais um erro, ele não faz o stop, fica girando a vida inteira, ele para em 0 mas não para em 90

Answer (score 0):

Com a observação do [@Ricardo Moraleida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5213/ricardo-moraleida) consegui chegar ao seguinte código

```
        var max_pespective_rotatex = 90;
    var min_pespective_rotatex = 0;
    var rotateX = max_pespective_rotatex - ( max_pespective_rotatex * ($(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height()));
    console.log(rotateX);
    if (rotateX > max_pespective_rotatex) {
        rotateX = max_pespective_rotatex;
    } else {
        rotateX = rotateX; }
    if (rotateX < min_pespective_rotatex) {
        rotateX = min_pespective_rotatex;
    } else {
        rotateX = rotateX; }
    $('div.primeirapagina div.mainpespective').css('transform', 'rotatex(' + rotateX + 'deg)');
```

Onde consegui colocar o stop e reformular a lógica, deixando aqui para quem precisar um dia.